# What is the correct way to use socket.io with Redis Adapter on Nest.js

Tags: redis, socket.io, nestjs

I am trying to create a sample Nest.js app to have websocket connections using socket.io which uses Redis Adapter to publish event to multiple microservices.

Seems like in Redis v4 when the client is created it doesn't connect automatically anymore.

I have the following adapter:

```js
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';

const pubClient = createClient({
  url: 'redis://redis:6379',
  password: 'pass',
});

const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

const redisAdapter = createAdapter(pubClient, subClient);

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  override createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);

    server.adapter(redisAdapter);

    return server;
  }
}
```

When calling `this.server.to('room').emit()` I am getting the following error:

```
server  | /app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:407
server  |         return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
server  |                               ^
server  | 
server  | ClientClosedError: The client is closed
server  |     at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:407:31)
server  |     at Commander.commandsExecutor (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:166:154)
server  |     at Commander.BaseClass.<computed> [as publish] (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
server  |     at RedisAdapter.broadcast (/app/node_modules/@socket.io/redis-adapter/dist/index.js:406:28)
server  |     at BroadcastOperator.emit (/app/node_modules/socket.io/dist/broadcast-operator.js:109:22)
server  |     at AppGateway.handleMessage (/app/dist/app.gateway.js:21:30)
server  |     at /app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-context-creator.js:43:33
server  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
server  |     at async AppGateway.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-proxy.js:11:32)
server  |     at async WebSocketsController.pickResult (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:91:24)
server  | 
server  | Node.js v17.4.0
server exited with code 1
```

I tried downgrading to `"redis": "^3.1.2"` and `"socket.io-redis": "^6.0.0"` and updated the relevant code (for example, to use `RedisClient` instead of `createClient`) and everything seems to be working well (I tried this in k8s using three servers and all clients received the message).

I want to use the latest versions however. Considering that `RedisClient.connect` is an async function, what is the correct way to connect to Redis in this case? The `createIOServer` is also not an async function, so I cannot call `connect` in there either.

---

Just for reference, here is my `main.ts` file:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(app));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and `app.gateway.ts`:

```js
import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

type Payload = {
  name: String;
  text: String;
};

@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})
export class AppGateway {
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: Payload) {
    this.server.to('msgRoom').emit('msgToClient', payload);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    client.join('msgRoom');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should user redis3 `npm i --save redis@3`. Only [microservices docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/redis#redis) tell us about it, but is valid to entire Nest packages.

```js
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { Server, ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { createClient } from 'redis';

import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigurationService } from 'src/configuration/configuration.service';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  protected redisAdapter;

  constructor(app: INestApplication) {
    super(app);
    const configService = app.get(ConfigurationService);

    const pubClient = createClient({
      host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
      port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
    });
    const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

    this.redisAdapter = createAdapter(pubClient, subClient);
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions) {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options) as Server;

    server.adapter(this.redisAdapter);

    return server;
  }
}
```

It works with redis@4 (https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/#usage)

```js
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { Server, ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { createClient } from 'redis';

import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigurationService } from 'src/configuration/configuration.service';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  protected redisAdapter;

  constructor(app: INestApplication) {
    super(app);
    const configService = app.get(ConfigurationService);

    const pubClient = createClient({
      socket: {
        host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
      },
    });
    const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

    pubClient.connect();  // <------
    subClient.connect();  // <------

    this.redisAdapter = createAdapter(pubClient, subClient);
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions) {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options) as Server;

    server.adapter(this.redisAdapter);

    return server;
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured out looking at this https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/#usage. You need only connect both clients.
```
    pubClient.connect();
    subClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a function in `redis-io.adapter.ts` to connect to clients:

```js
export async function connectRedis() {
  if (pubClient.isOpen && subClient.isOpen) return;

  await Promise.all([pubClient.connect(), subClient.connect()]);
}
```

I am calling it in `main.ts`, right before `useWebSocketAdapter`

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  await connectRedis();
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(app));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I also moved the `createAdapter` call inside `createIOServer`, this way whenever the adapter is created the Redis clients will always be connected. Seems to be working fine now, just like with the older versions.