# Having 2 open connections to 2 separate Redis Instances on Nestjs Websocket server giving Connection Error

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, nestjs

I've been tinkering around with this chat app project I started a bit back and am running into a little trouble with connecting to 2 separate Redis instances. Note, if this is dumb and not a good move, feel free to let me know.

So initially I had a a single Redis Instance handling Pub/Sub for my Socket.IO server, I used this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120056/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-socket-io-with-redis-adapter-on-nest-js) on here as an example.

Then I wanted to add another Redis Instance to work as my cache/temp db for meta-data, but when I added that code and run it I get this error.

> Error: Redis is already connecting/connected

From that error I'm thinking I'm not able to have two separate connections to 2 different servers open? Or I'm doing it incorrectly maybe?

Is there a way I can get this configured correctly to have 2 open connections to 2 different servers?

RedisClientFactory Code: (This connects to the Redis DB Instance, port 6380)

This code is getting called/executed in the RedisModule then in AppModule.

```
import { FactoryProvider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import Redis from 'ioredis';

export const redisClientFactory: FactoryProvider<Redis> = {
  provide: 'RedisClient',
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const redisInstance = new Redis({
      port: configService.get('REDIS_DB_PORT'),
      host: configService.get('REDIS_DB_HOST')
    });

    redisInstance.on('error', (e) => {
      throw new Error(`Redis connection failed: ${e}`);
    });

    return redisInstance;
  },
  inject: [ConfigService]
};
```

RedisIOAdapter Code: (This connects to the other instance, pub/sub, port 6379)
This code is getting called/executed in the main.ts bootstrap method.

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { Redis } from 'ioredis';
import { Server, ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import * as util from '../shared/util';

import { INestApplicationContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

const host = util.isLocal() ? 'localhost' : 'redis';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  protected redisAdapter;

  constructor(private app: INestApplicationContext) {
    super(app);
    const configService = this.app.get(ConfigService);
    const port: string = configService.get('REDIS_IO_PORT') || '';
    if (!port || port.length <= 0 || !host) {
      throw Error('Issue creating the Redis URL');
    }
    const pubClient = new Redis({
      host,
      port: Number(port)
    });
    const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

    pubClient.connect(); // <------
    subClient.connect(); // <------

    this.redisAdapter = createAdapter(pubClient, subClient);
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions) {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options) as Server;

    server.adapter(this.redisAdapter);

    return server;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it a bit more, I believe its a library limitation as once I switched libraries to `node-redis` instead, it seemed to work with no hiccups.

Summary, if you are needing to have more than one distinct Redis connection open at a time, then `node-redis` should be used as client library instead of `ioredis`.

Code changes:

```
const client = createClient({
   socket: {
      host,
      port
   }
});
```